# Is there any relation between Pearson's beta and gamma coefficients?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

There exists four $\beta$ and $\gamma$ coefficients for a distribution that describe the shape of a distribution. I know the relation between $\beta_1 $ and $\gamma_1 $ which is $\gamma_1 = \sqrt \beta_1$ and similarly $\gamma_2 = \beta_2 - 3$.

But is there any other relation between $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ or a relation between $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$?

I tried searching but I couldn't find anything. Sorry if I am asking something very obvious, maybe I am just a noob.

Comment: Note $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are non-negative, while $\gamma_1$ (the skewness) can be positive or negative and $\gamma_2$ (excess kurtosis) is no less than $-2$.  There is a very mild constraint between them, namely $\beta_2 \ge \beta_1+1$ i.e $\gamma_2 \ge \gamma_1^2 -2$ (equalities with Bernoulli distributions), since a large magnitude of skewness pushes out one of the tails and so increases the kurtosis above what might otherwise be its minimum. By contrast you can have any possible value of kurtosis while having zero skewness.

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the answer.